# how to active 4 same Data ID when onClick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i wanna to click one button which is "c-1" but it can active and display the content for all same id,but in the same time, what can i add in to call all in different div?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mark-container">
  <div class="c-1" data-id="tab-1">
    <p>for 1 btn</p>
  </div>

  <div class="c-1-details" id="tab-1">
    <p>for 1 details</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="second-mark">
  <ul>
    <li class="tab-corner" data-tab="tab-1">tab-1-btn</li>
  </ul>

    <div class="tab-content" id="tab-1">
      tab-1-content
    </div>
</div>


<script>
  $('.c-1').click(function() {
    var tab = $(this).attr('data-id');

    $('.c-1').removeClass('active');
    $(".c-1-details").removeClass('active');

    $(this).addClass('active');
    $("#" + tab).addClass('active');
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You want `c-1` onclick all the `tab-1` id div will be active or what?

Comment: yaya,i wan to be do like that,

Comment: If I understand  what you want, You want active all tab which have same id? then you can use `.nextAll()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note** :Id is unique one .so better use class for multiple element match

I just coded from multiple id matches with attr matching `[id="tab"]`

```js
$('.c-1').click(function() {
    var tab = $(this).attr('data-id');

    $('.c-1').removeClass('active');
    $(".c-1-details").removeClass('active');

    $(this).addClass('active');
    $("[id='"+tab+"']").addClass('active');
  });
```

```css
.active{
color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="mark-container">
  <div class="c-1" data-id="tab-1">
    <p>for 1 btn</p>
  </div>

  <div class="c-1-details" id="tab-1">
    <p>for 1 details</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="second-mark">
  <ul>
    <li class="tab-corner" data-tab="tab-1">tab-1-btn</li>
  </ul>

    <div class="tab-content" id="tab-1">
      tab-1-content
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! But if  want the "tab-1-btn" in the second-mark div also can click and active the tab-1-content,?

Comment: sorry @annieylooi .i m not clear with your point.give some specific scenario